# creating insert trigger error

Tags: oracle, triggers

i'm trying to create a trigger that sets the id from a predefined sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_list_status 
    START WITH 1 
    INCREMENT BY 1 

;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_list_status_insert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON list_status 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    select seq_list_status.nextval into :new.id from dual; 
/
```

i'm getting the error below while creating the trigger

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_list_status_insert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON list_status 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    select seq_list_status.nextval into :new.id from dual
Error at Command Line:4 Column:4
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
04079. 00000 -  "invalid trigger specification"
*Cause:    The create TRIGGER statement is invalid.
*Action:   Check the statement for correct syntax.
```

i googled it but it seems all ok. any idea for what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing the `begin` `end`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_list_status_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON list_status 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
select seq_list_status.nextval into :new.id from dual; 
END;
/
```

Answer (score 6):

Triggers are program units.  Consequently we must wrap the code body in BEGIN and END.  Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_list_status_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON list_status
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    select seq_list_status.nextval into :new.id from dual;
END;
/
```

Unfortunately [the examples in the SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm#i2153487) are not as helpful as we would like.  But it does link to other useful documents, such as [the App Developers Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#i1025109).